MySQL via SSH tunneling refuses user credentials
I initiate an SSH tunnel like so:
ssh -L 12345:127.0.0.1:51874 remote_server
Where 51874 is the port MySQL listens on (on the host, mapped to 3306 in a container) on remote_server. This works as expected.
I now connect (in another terminal) like so:
mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -P 12345 --protocol tcp -h 127.0.0.1 --get-server-public-key=TRUE
I use the CLI password here for debugging, not as a long term solution. I get a connection, but I get rejected with:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.89.0.14' (using password: YES)
The user root is defined as 'root'@'%', with the password set to the same one provided in the command line above through Ctrl+V, minus the -p, so no typing mistake or similar is possible here. I can also use the password from above to log in through tools such as PHPMyAdmin.
What else could be resulting in the 'access denied' message I am seeing ? Are there config options in MySQL beyond the 'regular' user management I should be looking at ?
I believe despite the other aspects, the error message I am seeing can only be rooted in MySQL, so I'm leaving the other tags off unless anyone sees a reason to add them.
Edit: following some IRC advice, I confirmed that the user in question does not have the unix_socket plugin configured, but the caching_sha2_password, so that doesn't explain the refusal to accept my login either. Logging in as other users also works, its only the root user that refuses login.
